# Calculate the homology and homotopy groups of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory

Calculate the homotopy groups of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$.

And I have a hint there is a fibre sequence $S^1 \rightarrow S^{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}.$

But still I do not know how to calculate homotopy groups, Could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: What do you know about the relationship between fiber sequences and homotopy groups?

Comment: You ask about homology in the title but not the question. You should use the fact that $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is the $2n$-skeleton of $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$, and compute that $H_{2i}(\mathbb{C}P^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ for all $0\leq i \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise by induction on $n$, using the long exact sequence of the pair along with the fact that $\mathbb{C}P^n/\mathbb{C}P^{n-1} \cong S^{2n}$.

Answer (score 2):

$S^{\infty}$ is contractible, the Serre exact sequence gives $\pi_{n+1}(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})=\pi_n(S^1)$.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198/how-do-you-show-that-s-infty-is-contractible

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group#Long_exact_sequence_of_a_fibration